# interaction with web element using selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automation, cucumber

I need to interact with this element to log out using selenium, cucumber and java but it's not working:

[desired element mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CF1b.png)

[message displayed on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp4Yw.png)

Below is part of my code with only the methods I used to try to log out, remembering that for other mappings it worked:

```
class Generic
public void waitDesiredElement (By element) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(element));
}

class LoginPage
private By signOut = By.xpath("//label[@ng-click='signOut($event)']");
public By getSignOut () {
    return signOut;
}

class LoginLogic
public void logout () {
    waitDesiredElement(login.getSignOut());
    click(login.getSignOut());
}

class LoginStep
@When("^realizo logout$")
public void logoutThePage () {
    login.logout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to logout there you have first to click on user menu so that the menu will open and logout option element will be visible and clickable.
Also I would advice you to use element visibility or clickability expected conditions rather that element presence only since during the element creating process on the page it may already be existing (present) on the page but still not clickable / visible.
Try this:

```java
class Generic
public void waitDesiredElementVisibility (By element) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
}

class LoginPage
private By signOut = By.xpath("//label[@ng-click='signOut($event)']");
private By userMenu = By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='UserMenu']");
public By getSignOut () {
    return signOut;
}
public By getUserMenu () {
    return userMenu;
}

class LoginLogic
public void logout () {
    waitDesiredElementVisibility(login.getUserMenu());
    click(login.getUserMenu());
    waitDesiredElementVisibility(login.getSignOut());
    click(login.getSignOut());
}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention but the method to click the user has already been implemented and it's working perfectly, the problem is that after clicking the user he can't click logout

Comment: OK, the problem still can be caused by the fact that you are waiting for element presence. Try using waiting for element visibility as I used here.